# How can I add a default image in the form file upload field in wordpress jet form builder

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have an application form where I want to add a default image showing before the applicant uploads his image and I'm using Jet form builder and Elementor free version In wordpress, Is there any solution to resolving this issue?

I've seen all the settings and also tried to add custom scripts but it was no use

Answer (score 0):

check this , must be correctly working

```html
 
add_filter( 'jet-form-builder/customizer/controls', function( $controls ) {

$default_image = 'https://example.com/default-image.jpg'; // change your default image url 
    $controls['jet-form-builder-image-control']['default'] = $default_image 
    return $controls;
} );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).